# JSON LD + Schema.org - only on homepage or on all pages?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

I am tasked with adding JSON-LD (using Schema.org) to our website. I am reading up on it, but I do not seem to get some conclusive answers. It'd be great if some could answer, or point to any site that might have answers for these questions.

1. Should the JSON-LD go on all pages of the website or just the homepage?
2. If it should (or could) go in all pages, should the content be different or can it be the same?